# Basic python IO, please melp understanding file directory usage.

Tags: python, pandas, io

This works:

```
fpath = 'D:\\OSGM\\Data\\'
fname_in = 'OGSM_filtJul13.csv'
full_name_in = fpath + fname_in
dataframe = pd.read_csv(full_name_in)
```

But this does not:

```
Dat = pd.read_csv('D:\\OGSM\\Data\\OGSM_filtJul13.csv')
```

And returns:
FileNotFoundError: File b'D:\OGSM\Data\OGSM_filtJul13.csv' does not exist

Clearly these is something I am missing about IO file/directory syntax.

Any advice?
P

Comment: First, check whether file is there or not, are you using correct path? because `FileNotFoundError` error clearly states that file is not there

Comment: In windows you can try something like: r`D:\OSGM\Data\` to avoid double backslashes

Comment: I posted an answer, could you test it and tell me if it explains what you have ? 
I'm still intrigued by the error's type : `FileNotFoundError`, all I could get is `OSError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem seems that your string is coerced to bytestring. I recreated your problem:

First, with a bytestring

```
> pd.read_csv(b'test.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 384, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 713, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
OSError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type
```

Whereas :

```
>  pd.read_csv('test.csv')
output:
=> Empty DataFrame
Columns: [foo;bar]
Index: []

>  pd.read_csv(u'test.csv')
=> Empty DataFrame
Columns: [foo;bar]
Index: []
```

To avoid this kind of problems, **especially in windows**, 
Try using proper os.path methods to join paths :

```
import os

fpath = os.path.join("D:", os.sep, "OSGM", "Data")
fname_in = 'OGSM_filtJul13.csv'
full_name_in = os.path.join(fpath,fname_in)
dataframe = pd.read_csv(full_name_in)
```

N.B: In python2, the problem doesn't seem to occur.

Comment: Yes that works.  The file was definitely there.  I'll start using the os.path methods.  Thanks!